# carousel setInterval autoplay not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, setinterval, autoplay

the code: http://jsfiddle.net/n2m4absf/ (wont be functional, this is linked for code display purposes). trying to use:

```
setInterval(function(){slideCard();}
, 5000);
```

this carousel is a div box that moves in -883px chunks of margin-left. i want it to scroll automatically (thinking set interval would be the logic to use) every 5 seconds or so.

i have other js that handles the on click functions for navigating the carousel manually, but i dont think they should be effecting the autoplay. they do however live in the same file as the above js.

just need to get autoplay working and not sure why my js isnt doing it.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: The variable `count` should be declared outside of the `slideCard` method

Comment: You need to start by including jQuery in your fiddle.

Comment: jquery is included in my project, thats just a snippet

Comment: Well you should make the fiddle work....Do you know how many people have that issue on this site... a lot...

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen why would i need to do that anyway when anyone can add it themselves by selecting it in the frameworks pane?

Comment: @epascarello ...my carousel is so simple, this should be solve-able by just looking at the js + html ....i just cant figure it out. doesnt make sense to me why this doesnt work.

Comment: @heug but as the person who is asking for help, it is your duty to give us a proper sample, we can't simply guess that you have included jQuery

Comment: @heug we will also need the css part if you want a proper solution

Comment: If you want a complete answer, do not give a half-baked example.

Comment: css is actually not important to show here at all....im sry guys, but the time spent rigging up this carousel in fiddle would honestly not be worth it...@ArunPJohny already provided me a half-baked solution and it did help, and he's right, i should have atleast mentioned jquery was in the project or included it in fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in the script.

1. The variable count is declared as local to the method so in every call it will get initiated to `0` causing the first `if` block to execute.
2. Since you have used different `if` blocks, each `if` blocks will get evaluated in each iteration, so only the value of the last block will be affected

Since you don't have a constant logic for the margin value, I think you can use an array of margin values like

```
var slide = $('div.inner > ul');

var count = 0,
    margins = ['-883px', '-1686px', 0];

function slideCard() {
    slide.css('margin-left', margins[count++ % 3]);
};

setInterval(function () {
    slideCard();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: thank you!! this clever modulus logic works for me. now just need make the manual toggle dots match up with the current number slide that is showing.